# Copy constructor that copy other object values

Tags: java

This is my Class:

```
public class City
{
    private String _cityName;
    private Point _cityCenter;
    private Point _centralStation;
    private long _numOfResidents;
    private int _noOfNeighborhoods;
    private final long RESIDENTS_CONST_VALUE = 0;
    private final int NEIGHBORHOODS_CONST_VALUE = 1;
}
```

One of my constructor is Copy from other object (same object):

```
public City(City other)
{
    _cityName = other._cityName;
    _cityCenter = other._cityCenter;
    _centralStation = other._centralStation;
    _numOfResidents = other._numOfResidents;
    _noOfNeighborhoods = other._noOfNeighborhoods;      
}

public Point(Point point)
{
    _x = point._x;
    _y = point._y;
}
```

This constructor get another `City` object and copy it's values.
My question is if what i have done it's OK to avoid aliasing or i need to do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see is with the reference to the `Point` class (I'm assuming that we are taking about `java.awt.Point`). This class is mutable, so the `City` class you are copying from can change it, and the change will be reflected in your copy also. Use the following code to copy the Point object:

```
_cityCenter = new Point(other._cityCenter);
_centralStation= new Point(other._centralStation);
```

The rest of the fields are either primitives or immutable, so it is OK

Comment: And its will be OK if my Point copy method is like in my example (see my update) ?

Comment: Ah, so it is a custom class. I would propose to make the class immutable. If you cannot, then yes, your implementation is ok (_x any _y are primitives, right?)

Comment: _x and _y are type int, in this case this is OK ?

Comment: Yes, ints are primitives

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are copying the reference from old object to new.It will create problems while copying mutable fields.If both of the objects share common reference to a field, changing the value in one object will affect copied object as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done looks sane, at least because you haven't copied the `Point` objects, those are most likely mutable, i.e. if you copy them by simple assignment you would copy only the reference and changes to one object will reflect in the 'copy' -> shallow copy. If you need to make a copy of them too then you'll have to implement a "copy constructor" for them too.

However the standard way of doing this in java is to implment the [Colneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface and override the [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method.